# Pandas: Product of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, product

Finding the product of all columns in a dataframe is easy:

```
df['Product'] = df.product(axis=1)
```

How can I specify which **column names** (not column numbers) to include in the product operation?

From the help page for [DataFrame.product()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.product.html), I am not sure whether it is possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `df[[colname1, colname2, colname3...]]` syntax to select the columns you want and then call `.product` on that:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,2], "B": [3,3], "C": [5,5]})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  2  3  5
1  2  3  5

[2 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df[["A", "C"]].product(axis=1)
0    10
1    10
dtype: int64
```

Comment: OK thanks, the other solution I could think of was with `apply()`. I will test which one is faster.