# Multiply list of columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I have a DataFrame (`df`), with the following columns:

```
cols = ['A','B','C','D']
```

How can I multiply the values in these columns to form a single column called 'VAL'?

I can do this: `df['VAL'] = df['A']*df['B']*df['C']*df['D']`

But this will not scale; I want to use the `cols` variable to multiply these columns together.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21167614

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the columns in the list using `loc` and then use `.prod()` across the rows (by specifying `axis=1`). For example:

```
>>> cols = ['A','B','C','D']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 4, size=(3,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  2  2  1  1
1  2  3  1  1
2  3  1  3  3

>>> df['VAL'] = df.loc[:, cols].prod(axis=1)
>>> df
   A  B  C  D  VAL
0  2  2  1  1    4
1  2  3  1  1    6
2  3  1  3  3   27
```

Comment: axis =1 meaning that we iterate across columns?

Comment: @user308827: that's correct - `axis=1` means perform the method across the columns of the DataFrame.

Comment: thanks @ajcr, makes sense. I do see in several places, axis=1 for operations across rows.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. The `axis` thing can take a little while to get used to in pandas: [here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25774395/3923281) I wrote a little while ago explaining which axis refers to what.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you want the product so that, for every row, you have the product of a,b, c and d for that row.

You can use the apply method:

df['VAL'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A * x.B * x.C * x.D, axis=1)

Comment: sorry, i do not want to use column names explicitly